# SQL WHERE and AND not returning values

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have 3 tables:

- News (**ArticleID**, Title, ArticleImage)
- Categories (**EntryID**, *ArticleID*, *CategoryID*, CategoryName)
- CategoryList (**CategoryID**, CategoryName)

**Bold: PK**, *Italic: FK*

What I want to achieve: select rows of table `News` that belong to `CategoryName` 'Hot' **and** 'New'.

Here's my query:

```
select 
    n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName
from 
    News as n
inner join 
    Categories as c on n.ArticleID = c.ArticleID
inner join 
    CategoryList as cl on cl.CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
where 
    cl.CategoryName = 'Hot' 
    and cl.CategoryName = 'New'
group by 
    n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName
```

However, it does not return anything, but it should, since I have entries in the table `News` that belong to both categories 'New' and 'Hot'.

If instead of

```
cl.CategoryName = 'Hot' and cl.CategoryName = 'New'
```

I use

```
cl.CategoryName = 'Hot' or cl.CategoryName = 'New'
```

It returns those that belong to category 'Hot' plus those who belong to category 'New'.

[image: OR result, IN(,) result]
NOTE: 'Novidade' is what i refer to 'New'
I want to return 1, 4, 10.

So why **or** works, but **and** does not? How can I make **and** work?

Comment: Why would you expect `and` and `or` to do the same thing?

Comment: why this question is upvoted ?why having categoryname is both table.It is bad example of denormalisation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course not.  The `CategoryName` cannot be two things at once.  If you want new articles that are in both groups, here is one way:

```
select n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage
from News n inner join
     Categories c
     on n.ArticleID = c.ArticleID inner join
     CategoryList cl
     on cl.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
where cl.CategoryName in ('Hot', 'New')
group by n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage
having count(distinct cl.CategoryName) = 2;
```

Note that the `CategoryName` has been removed from the `select` and `group by`.

The `where` clause gets articles that have the two categories.  The `having` checks that both are on the article.

Comment: I was thinking of this but for OP `OR` condition works so left this option

Comment: @prdp . . . I interpreted that as saying: "`OR` works to get articles with either category.  Why doesn't `AND` work to get articles with both?".

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your input. Unfortunately I get no results with such query. Please see my updated post with what I get with both OR and IN(,). What I actually want is ID 1,4 and 10. Thanks

Comment: @Lernas . . . This query should return those three articles (with `'Novidade'` replacing `'New'`, of course).  Are you sure you removed `CategoryName` from the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Gordon, both your and Tanjim's queries work. Not sure what I did wrong on my first attempt, but it works now. Since your code was posted first and it is a more consise query, I will mark yours as the answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you don't understand the difference between `AND` and `OR`

`AND` - Implies that the conditions *Before* **and** *After* `AND` operator should satisfy. In your case it is impossible to have a single row with *CategoryName* both `Hot` and `New`.

`OR` - Implies that the conditions *Before* **or** *After* `OR` operator satisfies then return the row. In your case it returns the result.

But the correct way to do this would be using `IN` operator

```
where cl.CategoryName IN ( 'Hot' , 'New' )
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Both IN(,) and OR return the same result. How can I filter it further, so that no entries of Table Rows are repeated in the result query?

Comment: @Lernas - Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: OP you are right, That is becouse IN is an abreviated way to do multiple ORs

Comment: @Lernas - Did you check Gordan's answer. I think you are looking for that answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method using CTE to get your result.

```
;with cte_1
 AS
(SELECT 
      n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName
       ,COUNT(1) OVER(partition by   n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName order by n.ArticleId) CNT
  FROM News as n
     INNER JOIN Categories as c on n.ArticleID = c.ArticleID
     INNER JOIN CategoryList as cl on cl.CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
   WHERE  cl.CategoryName IN ( 'Hot' ,'New')
 )
SELECT ArticleID, Title, ArticleImage, CategoryName
FROM cte_1
WHERE CNT =2
```

Answer (score 0):

And will never work because no row exists that have Hot or New together; I mean 1, 4, 10 have but in different rows.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select 
    n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName
    from 
    News as n
    inner join 
    Categories as c on n.ArticleID = c.ArticleID
    inner join 
    CategoryList as cl on cl.CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
    where cl.CategoryName = 'Hot' 
    group by 
    n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName
) AS A
INNER JOIN
(
    select 
    n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName
    from 
    News as n
    inner join 
    Categories as c on n.ArticleID = c.ArticleID
    inner join 
    CategoryList as cl on cl.CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
    where cl.CategoryName = 'New'
    group by 
    n.ArticleID, n.Title, n.ArticleImage, cl.CategoryName
) AS B ON A.ArticleID = B.ArticleID
```

**For AND Operator**
AND means there should be a row with Category name 'New' AND 'Hot'. That is not possible ever. You have 2 rows for 1, 4 & 10 each but none of these 6 rows have category name 'New' and 'Hot' together.

**For OR/IN Operator**
OR means to choose those rows having category name either 'Hot' or 'New' and now you got all rows as return value.

**My Approach**
I just choose values with 'New' and 'Hot' differently and select their common parts by INNER JOIN. Nothing hard man. I think you should read more about SQL JOINS.

***And yes, I go for the simplest way but you should follow @Gordon's smarter way.***

Comment: Yes, you did! Thanks a lot man. I'm still a little bit confused on why this query works and others I've tried did not, i will have to study it a little bit more in depth.

Comment: @Lernas if this was useful for you, you should up-vote it.

Comment: @LuisSiquot I did upvote the answer, it does not show because I have less than 15 points of reputation. Thanks